# How to set bitmap to webview in android

Tags: android, bitmap, webview

I am using webview for pinch zoom. I have to draw circle after zoom in touch portion. I am trying to draw circle using canvas.I have to set the bitmap back to web view after drawing the circle. Currently I am able to load the image using the below code but no idea how to draw circle in touch portion.

How to set bitmap to webview after drawing the circle?

(or)  How to draw circle on webview?

I am using below code to load image,

```
 <WebView 
 android:id="@+id/webview"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout">
 </WebView>

 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 String imagePath = "file:/"+ImagePath;
 String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>"
 mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///sdcard/data/data/com.colorsplashphoto.android/",
             html,
             "text/html",
             "utf-8",
             "");
```

Thanks in advance.